# Html input fields automatically fill

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two input Fields same value  one input fields have home page and another input fields same value have in results page.when i input the value in homepage this automatically Fill results page .if i enter value in home page 5000. this value automatically fill in same input fields Results page ? how i will  do this ? please help me ?

code :

```
     <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign gly pull-left">
          </div>
          <br />
    <p>Confirm 1st Mortgage For DPA Scenario</p>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
     <select id="Select9" class="dropdown">
      <option value="">Work with All Mortgages</option>
      </select>
      </div>
      </div>
       <br />
        <br />
  <p class="pull-right">DPA Minimum Buyer Contribution<br />
          (Unless Included In Down Payment)
          </p>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
         </div>
     <div class="col-md-6"  style="padding-right:1%">
         <input type="text" class="txt"/></div>
          <div class="col-md-3" style="padding-left:0%">
         <select id="Select10" class="dropdown"style="margin-top:1px">
            <option value="">%</option>
              </select></div>
              </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: your code only has one `input`, can you include all the code

Comment: @this same code have in results page  when i put value in home page  its automatically fill  insert value in results page

Comment: Are you asking how to post form values from one page to another and display them on that second page?  You would generally use server-side code for this.  The first page posts the values to the server-side code, which would in turn read those values and put them in the page being rendered as the response.

Comment: @David  yes value post from home page to results page same input fields

Comment: @thennarasumca2011: Are you using any server-side development platform, such as PHP or ASP.NET?  That's how you'd do this.  If you only have HTML and JavaScript then you wouldn't want to navigate from page to page like this and would instead probably want to keep the user on the same page (as a single-page application) and use JavaScript to implement the desired functionality.

Comment: i am using javascript  server side in php

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment:

> i am using javascript server side in php

You would use server-side code to accomplish this.  Let's look at a contrived example.  On the first page, you might have a simple form:

```
<form method="post" action="secondPage.php">
    <input type="text" name="myValue" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When submitting this form, the value in `myValue` is posted to the server-side code in `secondPage.php`.  That page can access the value:

```
$myValue = $_POST['myValue'];
```

Then to output it to the page, you would echo ([a sanitized version of](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)) the value:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($myValue);
```

This can happen anywhere in your markup.  For example, if you want it to be in another form element:

```
<input type="text" name="myValue" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($myValue); ?>" />
```